# How can I restrict users from accessing other pages by url?

Tags: php

There are 3 users logged in, and each one has their own profile page.
How can I restrict others from accessing other profile pages by url?

Comment: When a user requests access to a page or to specific data, you conditionally show them what they're allowed to see or return an error.

Comment: What you are asking is somebody to write an application for you....there is no a proper way to do so ! You must to write an algorithm according to your scope and needs

Answer (score 0):

Before outputting the contents of the profile page, check if the id of the currently logged in user is the same as the id of the owner of the page.

If it does not match show a "permission denied" page instead of the profile.